# SQL Server: value divided by rolling sum of last four values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the value divided by the last four values in SQL Server 2014?

---

**Example.** How can I get `ValueDIVbyLastFourValues` field from the `Value` field?

```
Month|Value| ValueDIVbyLastFourValues |
---------------------------------------
  1  |  1  |            1             |
  2  |  1  |            1/2           |
  3  |  2  |            2/4           |
  4  |  2  |            2/6           |
  5  |  1  |            1/6           |
  6  |  7  |            7/12          |
  7  |  4  |            4/14          |
```

**Bad Trial**

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER
    ,MONTH
    ,NET_VALUE_M / SUM(NET_VALUE_M) AS 'NET_VALUE_M_PROP_BY_YEAR'
FROM
    MY DATA
GROUP BY  LEFT(MONTH,4)
        ,CUSTOMER
        ,MONTH
        ,NET_VALUE_M
ORDER BY NET_VALUE_M_PROP_BY_YEAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, MONTH,
       (NET_VALUE_M /
        SUM(NET_VALUE_M) OVER (ORDER BY MONTH ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
       ) AS NET_VALUE_M_PROP_BY_YEAR
FROM MY DATA;
```

This uses a window function to sum the values in the current row and the preceding four rows.